# Processing requests using the user's time zone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have an application in Ruby on Rails (3.2) and I want all the requests to take into account the currently logged in user's time zone. Also, I want to have a helper that will let me display date time fields using user's time zone.

I follow this approach:

1. Inside `ApplicationController` I hook an `around_filter` like this:

   ```
   around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user
   ```
2. The implementation of `user_time_zone` is:

   ```
   def user_time_zone(&block)
     Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
   end
   ```
3. In `ApplicationController` as well, I have a helper method like so:

   ```
   helper_method :datetime_users_time_zone
   ```

   with implementation:

   ```
   def datetime_users_time_zone(datetime, user = nil)
     time_zone = user.present? ? user.time_zone : Time.zone_default
     datetime.in_time_zone(time_zone)
   end
   ```

Is this good practice and implementation? What might be the gotchas? If I were to implement this for Rails 4, what changes should I make?

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is displaying localized time in views then please handle it in frontend, i.e. using http://timeago.yarp.com/

Handling timezone in backend will be big pain when you try to add caching (you will need to cache same piece of content for each timezone).